# invertibility of a matrix with gaussian distances

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have have n points $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ and we create a matrix $A$ such that $a_{(i,j)}=e^{−(||x_i−x_j||_2)/\epsilon}$.

Is there a proof that A is invertible?